# Encrypt a short message

Tags: modular-function

I'm supposed to encrypt a short message, OAHU, using f(p) = (3p + 7) mod 26.

I've tried to understand how to use a modulo, but frankly I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

If someone could explain the process or at least point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letters OAHU correspond to the numbers $14,0,7$, and $20$ in that order. Substitute these successively for $p$ in the equation

$$f(p)=(3p+7)\bmod{26}\;;$$

I’ll do the first two. For the O we have $p=14$, so we want

$$(3\cdot14+7)\bmod{26}=(42+7)\bmod{26}=49\bmod{26}\;.$$

To find $n\bmod{m}$ you need to divide $n$ by $m$, throw away the quotient, and keep the remainder.

> When $n$ is negative this doesn’t work quite the way you probably expect, but that doesn’t happen here. An alternative approach that avoids this technical difficulty is as follows.
>
> - If $n>m$, subtract $m$ repeatedly until you get a result in the range $0,1,\ldots,m-1$; that result is $n\bmod{m}$.
> - If $n<0$, add $m$ repeatedly until you get a result in the range $0,1,\ldots,m-1$; that result is $n\bmod{m}$.

When you divide $49$ by $26$, you get a quotient of $1$ with a remainder of $20$, so $48\bmod{26}=20$. That corresponds to the letter U, so we encipher the O as U.

For A we have $p=0$, so we want

$$(3\cdot 0+7)\bmod{26}=7\bmod{26}=7\;,$$

since $7$ is already between $0$ and $25$ inclusive. $7$ corresponds to the letter H, so we encipher A as H. The encipherment of OAHU therefore begins UH.

Now see if you can finish the job.